# Send and receive traffic through the same network interface on Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking

I have 2 network interfaces connecting to 2 diferent ethernet cable through 2 bridges but when I started monitoring the data traffic I noticed that it received information from both interfaces but when it send the data back only through the main interface (eno1).

I made some reasearch and foud this code to make rules of how the traffic  will behave:

```
ip route add 192.168.15.0/24 dev br0 src 192.168.15.32 table T1
ip route add default via 192.168.15.32 dev br0 src 192.168.15.32 table T1
ip rule add from 192.168.15.32 table T1

ip route add 192.168.15.0/24 dev br1 src 192.168.15.29 table T2
ip route add default via 192.168.15.29 dev br1 src 192.168.15.29 table T2
ip rule add from 192.168.15.29 table T2
```

With this code the data flows correctly through each interface but I don't have internet connection.

Is this the right way to configure the network? 
How can I setup my network so I can connect to the internet with 2 independent bridges and make each interface traffic its own data?

Comment: You have the exact same commands written twice there, is that really what you meant to do?

Comment: Sorry, I already edited it

Comment: because you missing the main default gateway for the main table